# Concatenating Row Values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I was using Microsoft SQL server 2005 and was able to concatenate row values based on the following query:

```
SELECT e1.EMP_ID,
( SELECT cast(Sector_ID as varchar(10)) + ';'
FROM Employee_Sector_relationship e2
WHERE e2.Emp_ID = e1.Emp_ID
ORDER BY Sector_ID
FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Sectors
FROM Employee_Sector_Relationship e1
GROUP BY Emp_ID
```

But it doesn't work in Microsoft Server 2000. It gives me an error near the for keyword.
Can anyone help me to concatenate the row values in Microsoft Server 2000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technique that should work for you. You can execute this in one batch statement if you wish:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeList varchar(100)

SELECT @EmployeeList = COALESCE(@EmployeeList + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(Emp_UniqueID AS varchar(5))
FROM SalesCallsEmployees
WHERE SalCal_UniqueID = 1

SELECT @EmployeeList
```

For more information, see [Using COALESCE to Build Comma-Delimited String](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string).

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR XML PATH
```

is not available in sql server 2000.

This article discusses different approached for concatenating row values: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: actually - it **IS** available in SQL Server 2005 and up - but it's **NOT** available in SQL Server **2000**

Comment: which article are you talkin about