# How should I modify this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, group-by, concatenation

My SQL Server view

```
SELECT     
   geo.HyperLinks.CatID, geo.Tags.Tag, geo.HyperLinks.HyperLinksID
FROM
   geo.HyperLinks LEFT OUTER JOIN
       geo.Tags INNER JOIN
       geo.TagsList ON geo.Tags.TagID = geo.TagsList.TagID ON geo.HyperLinks.HyperLinksID = geo.TagsList.HyperLinksID WHERE HyperLinksID = 1
```

returns these...

```
HyperLinksID CatID Tags
1            2     Sport
1            2     Tennis
1            2     Golf
```

How should I modify the above to have results like

```
HyperLinksID CatID TagsInOneRowSeperatedWithSpaceCharacter
1            2     Sport Tennis Golf
```

**UPDATE:** As Brad suggested I came up here...

```
DECLARE @TagList varchar(100)
SELECT @TagList = COALESCE(@TagList + ', ', '') + CAST(TagID AS nvarchar(100))
FROM TagsList
WHERE HyperLinksID = 1
SELECT @TagList
```

Now the result looks like

```
HyperLinksID CatID TagsInOneRowSeperatedWithSpaceCharacter
1            2     ID_OF_Sport ID_OF_Tennis ID_OF_Golf
```

And of course I have to combine the contents **from** the`@TagList` variable and the **original** `SELECT` statement...

Which means that I'll have to wait for the holy SO bounty :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If SQL, try this post:

[Concatenating Row Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064940/concatenating-row-values)

If you want to try your hand at CLR code, there are examples of creating a custom aggregate function for concatenation, again, for MS SQL.

[This post](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) is pretty exhaustive with lots of ways to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 4):

Using the approach [from here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/07/06/871.aspx) to avoid any issues if your tag names contain special XML characters:.

```
;With HyperLinks As
(
SELECT 1 AS HyperLinksID, 2 AS CatID
),
TagsList AS
(
SELECT 1 AS TagId, 1 AS HyperLinksID UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS TagId, 1 AS HyperLinksID UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS TagId, 1 AS HyperLinksID
)
,
Tags AS
(
SELECT 1 AS TagId, 'Sport' as Tag UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS TagId, 'Tennis' as Tag UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS TagId, 'Golf' as Tag 
)
SELECT HyperLinksID,
       CatID       ,
      (SELECT mydata
       FROM    ( SELECT Tag AS [data()]
               FROM    Tags t
                       JOIN TagsList tl
                       ON      t.TagId = tl.TagId
               WHERE   tl.HyperLinksID = h.HyperLinksID 
               ORDER BY t.TagId 
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ) AS d ( mydata ) FOR XML RAW,
               TYPE
       )
       .value( '/row[1]/mydata[1]', 'varchar(max)' ) TagsInOneRowSeperatedWithSpaceCharacter
FROM   HyperLinks h
```

**Edit:** As KM points out in the comments this method actually automatically adds spaces so I've removed the manually added spaces. For delimiters other than spaces such as commas [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824203/how-should-i-modify-this-sql-statement/3842202#3842202) seems more appropriate.

If you know your data will not contain any problematic characters then a simpler (probably more performant) version is

```
SELECT CatID       ,
       HyperLinksID,
       stuff(
       ( SELECT ' ' + Tag 
               FROM    Tags t
                       JOIN TagsList tl
                       ON      t.TagId = tl.TagId
               WHERE   tl.HyperLinksID = h.HyperLinksID 
               ORDER BY t.TagId 
               FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 1, '') TagsInOneRowSeperatedWithSpaceCharacter
FROM   HyperLinks h
```

Comment: in your first code example (which tries to avoid expanding xml control characters), you always get two spaces following values within your `TagsInOneRowSeperatedWithSpaceCharacter` column.  one space seems to be automatic and the other is the one you manually append in.  The bad part is that the automatic space is between the value and the manual space.  Try it out, try to make this value `Sport, Tennis, Golf` from your first query.  You'll get `Sport , Tennis , Golf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FOR XML` in a correlated subquery. For a space-delimited list:

```
SELECT h.HyperLinksID, h.CatID
, TagList = (
    SELECT t.Tag AS [data()]
    FROM geo.TagList l
    JOIN geo.Tags t ON l.TagId = t.TagId
    WHERE l.HyperLinksID = h.HyperLinksID
    ORDER BY t.Tag
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM geo.HyperLinks AS h
WHERE h.HyperLinksID = 1
```

For any other delimiter:

```
SELECT h.HyperLinksID, h.CatID
, TagList = STUFF((
      SELECT ', '+t.Tag
      FROM geo.TagList l
      JOIN geo.Tags t ON l.TagId = t.TagId
      WHERE l.HyperLinksID = h.HyperLinksID
      ORDER BY t.Tag
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'')
FROM geo.HyperLinks AS h
WHERE h.HyperLinksID = 1
```

The subquery creates a delimited list, and then `STUFF(...,1,2,'')` removes the leading `,`.  `TYPE).value()` gets around most common problems w/ special characters in XML.