# SQL Server T-SQL concat aggregate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have this table

```
BirthDay     |Name
1-10-2010    | 'Joe'
2-10-2010    | 'Bob' 
2-10-2010    | 'Alice'
```

How can I get a result like this

```
BirthDay     |Name
1-10-2010    | 'Joe'
2-10-2010    | 'Bob', 'Alice
```

tks

Comment: Use [FOR XML PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824203/3841835#3841835). This is a dupe many times over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
set nocount on;
declare @t table (BirthDay datetime, name varchar(20))
insert into @t VALUES ('1-10-2010',     'Joe'  )
insert into @t VALUES ('2-10-2010',     'Bob'  )
insert into @t VALUES ('2-10-2010',     'Alice')
set nocount off

SELECT p1.BirthDay,
          stuff(
                   (SELECT
                        ', ' + p2.name  --use this if you want quotes around the names:  ', ''' + p2.name+''''
                        FROM @t p2
                        WHERE p2.BirthDay=p1.BirthDay
                        ORDER BY p2.name
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                   )
                   ,1,2, ''
               ) AS Names
      FROM @t p1
     GROUP BY 
        BirthDay
```

OUTPUT:

```
BirthDay                Names
----------------------- ------------
2010-01-10 00:00:00.000 Joe
2010-02-10 00:00:00.000 Alice, Bob

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with no need of deploy from Visual studio or dll file in server.

Copy-Paste and it Work!

http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/

```
dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE )
dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_D(VALUE ), DELIMITER )  
dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_DS(VALUE , DELIMITER , SORT_ORDER )
dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_S(VALUE , SORT_ORDER )
```