# SQL Server Insert Query help

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have the following code that I use in a Query to update a table called ListClientCasePresentingIncidents which uses a function called fnSplit to split a comma seperated nvarchar named @CasePresentingIncidents.

```
   IF ( @CasePresentingIncidents <> '' ) 
    INSERT  INTO ListClientCasePresentingIncidents
            ( PresentingIncident ,
              CaseID
            )
            SELECT  SplitText AS PresentingIncident ,
                    @CaseID
            FROM    fnSplit(@CasePresentingIncidents)
```

All of this works really well one record at a time, passing in a value for @CaseID and @CasePresentingIncidents.

The question is, how would I modify this code so that it took values from a table called ClientCase rather than 2 parameters? It would need to replace  @CaseID and @CasePresentingIncidents with the values from ClientCase.CaseID and ClientCase.CasePresentingIncidents. Many thanks.

Comment: is ClientCase.CasePresentingIncidents still a comma separated list or did you already split it out when you populated the table?

Comment: ClientCase.CasePresentingIncidents is a comma separated nvarchar(MAX) too. It has the same value type as @CasePresentingIncidents, in the same way as ClientCase.CaseID has the same type as @CaseID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I can see two ways of solving this:

1. Combine (concatenate) all the `ClientCase.CasePresentingIncidents` values that are to be processed, into one string and pass it as an argument to `fnSplit()` (i.e. `dbo.fnSplit()`?). Depending on what version of SQL Server you are using you might consider different ways of concatenating. If you need some guidance here, I think this could be a good starting point: [Concatenating Row Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064940/concatenating-row-values) (There many similar questions related to it and listed accordingly in the Related section.)
2. Use a cursor to call `dbo.fnSplit()` for every row of `ClientCase`. I should probably suggest creating a new table-valued function `dbo.fnSplitMultiple()` which would implement this approach. In your example then you would select from `dbo.fnSplitMultiple()` instead of `dbo.fnSplit()`.

If the resulting string can be very long, then maybe the first method, though otherwise probably more attractive, wouldn't be very appropriate. I haven't had much experience with handling very long strings server-side, using SPs and functions too, so I'm not sure, and to me cursors here would be just a backup option.